# Is there a poetic or metaphorical meaning to ゆびさき が かたくなる?

Tags: metaphor

I'm curious about the final line of the musician Kishi Bashi's song ["Atticus, in the Desert"](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107859428817/):

> あたま ふらふら ゆびさき が かたくなる

I understand the *direct* translation of this ("head dizzy fingertips get hard") but it seems as if there must be a figurative or poetic meaning to ゆびさき が かたくなる.  Otherwise it just sounds like disconnected nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

指先が硬くなる is not a well-known idiomatic phrase. Judging from the rest of the lyrics, the person(?) in the song is about to be swallowed by sand. So I feel this line suggests his finger is so dried that he cannot move his finger anymore.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  If anything I imagine the repeated phrase "you suck my finger" gives 指先が硬くなる a more *sexual* connotation, but I didn't know if finger-related metaphors are common in Japanese innuendo.